# mongodb error handling whlle using exec

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, error-handling

I have ExpressJS ,NodeJs, Mongoose application.
I have written mongodb code like below and it works fine.

```
module.exports.getStudentid = function(id, callback) {

    Student
        .find({ _id: id })
        .populate('marks')       
        .exec(callback);
}
```

But is it a good code in terms of error handling in NodeJS..Will it pass error to the next layer? How can I improve the above code to use proper error handling?

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html   CB details in sample code on this pg

Comment: I am using mongoose and i am more concerned about the error handling while using the construct which i used

Answer (score 0):

One thing should be define your callback function to support your error. Your callback should look like:

```
function (err, student) {
  if (err) {
     // handle error err, will have your error
     return;
  } 
  return student;
}
```

How do you pass it to the next layer would be based on what you do on the commented line... My suggestion, change this to use promises:

```
const Q                 = require('q');
module.exports.getStudentById = function getById(id) {
    let deferred = Q.defer();
    Student
        .find({ _id: id })
        .populate('marks')       
        .exec(function doAfterExec(err, student){ 
          if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
          }
          deferred.resolve(student);
    });
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

And then to call this, lets assume that you previous module is called `StudentIO`

```
const io = require("StudentIO");
io.getStudentById(id)
.then(function doSuccess(result) {
   console.log("yeeei!!!", result);
})
.fail(function doError(err) {
   console.log("buuu", err);
});
```

This could be even cleaner if you use the new `=>` syntax, but I did not included it since not sure if you are using it. So I've used regular function notations.

Hope this could throw some light. Take a look at Q and promises... it can get rid of the callback hell scenario really easily.